# Get Forward, Backward left right sesnor android

Tags: android, sensors

I have a small project, in need to detect the movement of the device
Ex:
i have my mobile held on a table
if i move the device left "like moving a PC mouse", i need to know
if i move it right, i need to know
if i move it forward, and backward i need to know

I searched and used many tutorials, but all the tutorials gave me numbers that changes a lot even when the device is not moved!!
i tried this

```
 if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER){
            mGravity = event.values.clone();
            // Shake detection
            float x = mGravity[0];
            float y = mGravity[1];
            float z = mGravity[2];
            mAccelLast = mAccelCurrent;
            mAccelCurrent = (float)Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y + z * z);
            float delta = mAccelCurrent - mAccelLast;
            mAccel = mAccel * 0.9f + delta;
            // Make this higher or lower according to how much
            // motion you want to detect
            if(mAccel > 0.0005){
                ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.XField)).setText("X:" + String.valueOf((x)));
                ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.YField)).setText("Y:" + String.valueOf((y)));
                ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.ZField)).setText("Z:" + String.valueOf(z));
            }
        }
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

From Android Documentation:

> Measures the acceleration force in m/s2 that is applied to a device on all three physical axes (x, y, and z), including the force of gravity.

i.e.accelerometer detects acceleration, not movement, not speed and not direction. In a nutshell: if your movement will be at constant speed the accelerometer will show 0. You need to write an algorithm that will parse speed and/or direction from the acceleration. It involves a lot of study about physics and mathematics. In a nutshell: integral of acceleration is speed, second integral of acceleration is direction. (Of course it is much more complex, but just to give you direction of where to start exploring).